# Find C Keywords inside a String with Python and Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find and print the beginning and ending indices of the C keywords inside the string

```
code = 'int main( void )\n{\nreturn 0;\n}'
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
pattern = '/\bint|void|return\b/'
temp = re.compile( pattern )
for result in temp.finditer( code ):
    print 'Found %s from %d to %d.' % ( result.group(), result.start(), result.end() )
```

However, only **'void'** is being found. Why is that?

Comment: If it's always going to be `int <something> return <something>;` why not simply match the string ? `code.find('int ')` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
src='''\
int main( void )
   {
      return 0;
   }
'''

import re

for key, span in ((m.group(1), m.span(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'\b(int|main|void|return)\b', src)):
    print key, span
```

Prints:

```
int (0, 3)
main (4, 8)
void (10, 14)
return (28, 34)
```

But I think using a set of keywords to validate found words in better than having all the words in a pattern.

Consider:

```
keywords={'int', 'main', 'void', 'return'}

for key, span in ((m.group(1), m.span(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'\b(\w+)\b', src) 
                                                          if m.group(1) in keywords):
    print key, span
```

Same output, but easier to add words.

Comment: You still want to keep the word-boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Python doesn't use forward slashes (`/`) to indicate the start and end of a regular expression pattern. By convention, raw strings are used instead. Raw strings are a way of avoiding special character encodings in strings. The most common example would be a newline character (`'\n'`). Normally these two characters would be transformed into the single special newline character, but if we want a *literal* forward slash followed by a *literal* n, we use a raw string like `r'\n'`. Alternatively, we could escape the backslash character and write it as `'\\n'`, but for a longer string with more special characters, we really want to avoid throwing in backslashes everywhere. As you may notice, raw strings are a very convenient method for writing regular expressions.

You forgot to make your pattern a raw string so the \b's are being interpreted as special escaped characters (in this case it translates into ASCII character #8 for whatever reason, not really sure why) instead of word boundaries. You can make any string literal a raw string by prepending an `r` before the string:

```
>>> re.findall('\bint|void|return\b', 'int main( void )\n{\nreturn 0;\n}')
['void']
>>> re.findall(r'\bint|void|return\b', 'int main( void )\n{\nreturn 0;\n}')
['int', 'void', 'return']
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the r prefix, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski Ah sorry, I missed the two forward slashes in your string. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
pattern = '/\bint|void|return\b/' # wrong
```

1. Python doesn't enclose patterns in `/`:

```
pattern = '\bint|void|return\b' # still wrong
```

2. You really want to make this a raw string, otherwise `\b` is interpreted as a control character:

```
pattern = r'\bint|void|return\b' # still wrong
```

3. You need to enclose your or-group in parentheses:

```
pattern = r'\b(int|void|return)\b' # yay
```

And then:

```
re.compile(pattern).findall(code)
# ['int', 'void', 'return']
```

In your original pattern, the entire thing was being interepreted as three separate or-sections:
`/\bint`, `void`, and `return\b/`, thus it was naturally only finding `void`.